# Excel formulas have stopped working

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel sheet which has basic + Array  excel formulas, earlier it used to work properly but for the last 1 week it is not give me desired result.

I have tried the following things but nothing seems to work.

1. Change the formula setting from manual to automatic.
2. Change the format of the cell from text to General.
3. No space before the equal sign.

Note: I am using 2010 excel and rest in my office uses 2013 and we shared everything on common folder. Is this can be one of the reason ?

Comment: You should at least post what formulas you are using, the Basic code, and what you are getting! Otherwise nobody has an idea of what is going on. No single formula is working? Not even if you create a new one?

Comment: @Andrew Will do that. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: You have to take small parts of each formula and test them, until you find which one is failing. For example, in an auxiliary cell just place the `MATCH(...)` function, if it fails, then in another cell place the `COUNTIF(...)` that is inside.

Comment: What's the range for `Contractlist`?

Comment: If you have generated a `#VALUE!` error somehow and are referencing that error value in another formula as a precedent either individually or as a range, the second formula will always produce the same `#VALUE!` error. You need to get to the deepest level of the precedence and work forward. As you fix one error, you may find that others with precedent ranges will fix themselves.

Comment: Could you solve your problem, @PrashantAgrawal?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the **ANZ** formula, the rows have to match. Someone inserted 12 rows into part of Trades worksheet and this expanded the range to U1:U65548 and Z1:Z65548. The AW column remains at AW1:AW65536. While the ranges can be offset from each other, they have to be the same size.

This shows up on your formula for the **FINEX** as well.